# AngularJS controller constructor and instantiation with arguments

Tags: angularjs

Is it possible to instantiate a controller in AngularJS and pass arguments to its constructor like in OOP ? I can't figure out how to refactor 3 identical controller with just variables name and content which change...

Thanx.

Comment: You can use `.value("valueId", someValue)` and inject it into controller with `function($scope,..., valueId)`

Comment: refactor the 3 controllers to a service and inject the service to each controller.

Answer (score 2):

If you have 3 separate sections on the page that have very similar controller code, it sounds like you should consider using a directive. Even if you don't need to control the DOM directly (which is the classic reason to use directive), and only need the standard Angular data-bindings, then this is a nice way to reuse controllers in different contexts by the attributes set on the directive.

You can see a working plunkr at

http://plnkr.co/edit/qclp6MOxGWP7Ughod4T8?p=preview

But the key point is directives can bind-to variables in their parent scope's controller. Say, in the parent scope you have 3 variables, so:

```
$scope.myVariable1 = 'Value 1';
$scope.myVariable2 = 'Value 2';
$scope.myVariable3 = 'Value 3';
```

Then you can setup 3 instances of the directive in the template:

```
<my-directive my-param="myVariable1"></my-directive>
<my-directive my-param="myVariable2"></my-directive>
<my-directive my-param="myVariable3"></my-directive>
```

Then each directive can use the variable in the 'my-param' attribute

```
scope: {
  'myParam':'='
}
```

The '=' means that in the scope of the directive you have a variable, called 'myParam', that is equal (+ bound to) the variable specified by the 'my-param' attribute on the directive. So on the template of the directive, you can use:

```
<div>Value of parameter: {{myParam}}</div>
```

And in the controller of the directive, you have access to is as:

```
$scope.myParam
```

And should then be able to customise its behaviour based on that instance's myParam.

Answer (score -3):

You can create services with a common interface and then pass the corresponding services to each controller through dependency injection. In my code this is the case of table controllers where the only thing that changes is the data source:

Imagine you have some code that looks like this

```
angular.module('myapp').controller('TableACtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = // get the data from some source
    $scope.someFunction = function () { ... };
    $scope.someOtherFunction = function () { ... };
}]);

angular.module('myapp').controller('TableBCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    $scope.data = // get the data from some other source
    $scope.someFunction = function () { ... };
    $scope.someOtherFunction = function () { ... };
}]);
```

It looks something like:

```
var tableCtrl = function($scope, dataSource) {
    $scope.data = dataSource.getData();
    $scope.someFunction = function () { ... };
    $scope.someOtherFunction = function () { ... };
};

angular.module('myapp')
    .controller('TableACtrl', ['$scope', 'dataSourceA', tableCtrl])
    .controller('TableBCtrl', ['$scope', 'dataSourceB', tableCtrl])

angular.module('myapp')
    .service('dataSourceA', function() {
       return {
           getData: function() { ... }
       };
    });
angular.module('myapp')
    .service('dataSourceB', function() {
       return {
           getData: function() { ... }
       };
    });
```

I would still put things within a module, so you don't pollute the global window. But that's a different issue.

Comment: You should really be using angular services for this, not using a global variable.

Comment: @MichaelTempest what are you talking about? Have you read what I have written? You are saying the exact same thing I've said.

Comment: Yes, you are inputting a global variable function that you are injecting into each controller. This is a bad practice. An angular service should be used. You are not creating a service

Comment: @MichaelTempest This is creating three controllers and the only things being injected are the $scope service and a dataSource service. The point is that he can create different dataSource services with a common interface and create new controllers by just registering them.

Comment: The problem is that you are still using a global variable, the dataSource in your case should write to a service i.e. angular.factory

Then the controllers should only look at the angular service. not just a global function

Comment: Of course, dataSource is a service he still has to register but that's what I've been saying all the time.
For each controller angular will inject the corresponding service.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/42871/discussion-between-curial-and-michael-tempest)

Comment: Every time I ask this question or read Stackoverflow related to this, the answer is to create a service. If the code is exactly the same is the 3 controllers except some variable names and paths, and that I want to have 3 different controller for isolating 3 scopes, if I have a service which gather the code and inject it into the 3 controllers, i would end up with no code in 3 controllers... I'm confused...

Comment: I just want to know : Is it possible to instantiate a controller in AngularJS and pass arguments to it like in traditional OOP ? if yes, how to do it ? if no, what is the other way : create a service ? But if the answer is no, I want to be sure that we cannot instantiate a controller. In the official doc there is $controller but there is no examples, and I can't see what is its use...

Comment: @peaceLion in my example I wanted to show how you can create a generic controller (tableCtrl) that is where all the common code would be and then register it in angular with different dependencies so that you end up with three different angular controllers. In this case you want to grab what's different and encapsulate it in one (or more services).

Comment: @curial : ok I understand your answer, and how do you encapsulate tableCtrl the angular way ?